# Remove Server Response Header IIS8 for error 400 and 500

Tags: security, server, header, response, iis-8

I need to remove server banner on my website. So far I have tried the following solutions which mainly points on editing web.config and using urlscan/urlrewrite:

[Remove Server Response Header IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178831/remove-server-response-header-iis7/12615970#12615970)

[Removing/Hiding/Disabling excessive HTTP response headers in Azure/IIS7 without UrlScan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803972/removing-hiding-disabling-excessive-http-response-)
headers-in-azure-iis7-without

[Remove Server Response Header IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178831/remove-server-response-header-iis7/1252865#1252865)

[Disabling IIS Server Response Headers in Case of 404 and 302 Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52766968/disabling-iis-server-response-headers-in-case-of-404-and-302-files)

These threads provided solutions to remove server banner but on instances of http server response 200 only. These does not remove server banners in instances of server response 302/400/500 just like the below response.

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Internal Server Error
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 0
```

Can someone redirect me on possible solutions? Thanks!

Comment: You might get some very basic ideas from https://blog.lextudio.com/everything-you-might-need-about-iis-server-header-58ca268547be

Comment: Thanks @LexLi I have tried the suggestions in your blog but its still showing the server header. :(

Comment: Your link contains all the methods to remove the Server Response Header. They should work. Can you show me how you tried it? For example, how did you create a url rewrite rule to remove the Server Response Header?

Comment: Hello @samwu, i tried url rewrite again, but instead of editing the config manually and adding the same config from the solutions on the above links. I followed this link instead and it worked: https://improveandrepeat.com/2020/01/how-to-remove-the-server-header-in-iis-8-5/

which is weird.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is mainly because the response is not being sent by the IIS server.

Since it is a bad request (400), the HTTP service itself is responding to it - rather than forwarding it to IIS. Therefore **the request never made it to IIS**.

To fix this you need to make modifications in Windows registry for HTTP service itself.

Follow these steps to do so

1. Open regedit
2. Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters`
3. If DisableServerHeader doesn't exist, create it (DWORD 32bit) and give it a value of 2. If it does exist, and the value isn't 2, set it to 2.
4. Reboot the server OR restart the HTTP service by calling `net stop http` then `net start http`